# How to display total users on dashboard

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this CI project in which sometimes I need to manage get the all users from database to display on my dashboard at backend. for example (TOTAL USERS? - 10 )

the users from database should be induce admin, editors, members etc

Comment: Annnddddd your question is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Users model you should put something like this :

```
public function get_UserNumber(){   

    $this->db->select("count(*) as no");                        
    $query = $this->db->get("users");          
    return $query->result();            

}
```

Dashboard controller should include these lines of code :

```
    $this->load->model('users_model');      
    $usersNo =  $this->users_model->get_UserNumber();   
    $data['totalUsersNo'] = $usersNo[0]->no;
```

And of course in your Dashboard view :

```
    <?php echo $totalUsersNo; ?>
```

Voila ... hope that helped !!!

Comment: Thanks you so much its really helpful - cheer